# How to get process ID of chromedriver.exe started by intern

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, intern

I want get process id of chromedriver.exe started by intern somewhere printed in Intern console log .. Is there any way to get it ?any code that needs to be added in intern.js ?

I am using intern 3.1.1

chrome 76

ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.25.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a great way to get Intern to display that information. Intern itself doesn't start or shutdown the chromedriver process -- that's managed by Selenium.

Comment: I managed to kill chromedriver.exe at the end -  one thread keeps on executing which lists currently running thread and child of java process ( selenium ) and at the end I kill the chromedriver.exe process if it still running  which makes sure that process gets killed each time